# Как в таком предложении расставлять знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение примерно такое:

> Кто из женщин не мечтал поехать на дачу, ведь это лучший отдых в
>   России.

Есть два вопроса:

1. Интересуют знаки препинания.
2. Как лучше написать: "Кто из женщин" или "Какая женщина"?

*На смысл предложения не обращайте внимания, оригинал выложить не могу.*

Answer (score 1):

**Можно написать так:**

(1) *Какая женщина не мечтала поехать на дачу,  ведь это лучший отдых в России.*

(2) *Какая женщина не мечтала поехать на дачу — ведь это лучший отдых в России.*

**Пояснение**

1) Со словом *женщина* лучше сочетаются формы ж. рода (какая, мечтала).

2) **ВЕДЬ** II. союз. 1. Присоединяет предложения, содержащие указание **на причину,** обоснование предыдущего высказывания.  Пора домой, в. уже поздно.

Ставится  **запятая или  тире** (если нужно подчеркнуть значение причины).

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всё же разделить на 2 предложения, тогда и знаки препинания сами встанут.

*Кто из женщин не мечтал поехать на дачу! Это лучший отдых в России.*

```
Как лучше написать: "Кто из женщин" или "Какая женщина"?
```

В данном случае одинаково. Смотря что там в самом предложении, про дачу молчу, странная мечта.